# Overloaded assignment operator in C++

Tags: c++, overloading, assignment-operator

I'm new to overloading so bear with me. In my object, I've defined an operator=, a copy constructor, and a destructor like I've read. Everything points to that it should be working but it doesn't. My object looks like this

```
class myObject
{
    public:
    myObject()
    {
        internalPtr = NULL;
    }

    myObject(const myObject& rhs)
    {
        internalPtr = rhs.internalPtr;
    }

    ~myObject()
    {
        delete[] internalPtr;
    }

    myObject& operator= (const myObject& rhs)
    {
        this->empty(); //this will delete[] internalPtr
        internalPtr = rhs.internalPtr;
        return *this;
    }

    //Other methods are used to allocate internalPtr with new when needed

    private:
    double* internalPtr;
}

myObject add(myObject A, myObject B)
{
    myObject C;
    //simple code to add A and B together and store it back into C.internalPtr
    return C;
}
```

When I run a test function that calls

```
C = add(A,B);   //A,B,and C are myObject
```

C will be empty and not contain the object that is returned by add()

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Actually you are doing nothing in `add(A,B)`. You are returning empty Object and even A and B are empty. You are adding what??

Comment: Where is `internalPtr` initialized with something other than `NULL`, and why are you using a pointer for this member at all?!? If you need an array of doubles use `std::vector<double>` or `std::array<double,N>` please.

Comment: In my actual code, I'm adding them as if they were matrices. I just omitted the code for brevity. Sorry if that was unclear

Comment: Its allocated from a member function that reads in a matrix from a file. Its allocated with new

Comment: You are not copying the actual data, just the pointer. Now you have two objects pointing to the same piece of data. This is what is called a shallow copy. You need to do a deep copy.

Comment: In the copy-assignment operator, when you do the assignment of the pointers, you then have *two* objects with a the same pointer. Think about what will happen when one of those objects gets destructed.

Comment: How would I do a deep copy? would I have to dereference them and set them equal?

Comment: @Jrw3 _"How would I do a deep copy?"_ As mentioned use `std::vector<double>` or `std::array<double,N>` instead of managing the memory allocation and copying on your own.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ my project depends on my usage of a C like double array on the heap instead of using vector, etc. Is there a good way I can do the deep copy with what i have?

Comment: It is always good to understand how the internals work. So my advise is to try and make this work. Then in the future use `std::vector<>`. But how to do a deep copy and how it differs from a shallow copy is left as an exercise. Hint: use Google.

Comment: @Jrw3 If you need to interface somewhere else using a `double*` you can simply use the `std::vector<double>::data()` function to get that pointer. Also note that `std::vector<double>` already manages that memory on the heap, internally it's simply the same as a _C like `double` array_.

Comment: @Jrw3 to do a deep copy you allocate the memory using `new` then copy the data from the argument into the newly allocated memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `<vector>`, you'll have to take care for the deep copy by cloning  the array.  But for this you need to keep trace of its size (let's assume it's a private member).

I hope that you are allowed to use `<algorithm>`, as it works also with arrays.

Your constructors would then look like:

```
myObject() : internalPtr(nullptr), size(0) { }  // init size  

myObject(const myObject& rhs) : internalPtr(nullptr), size(rhs.size)  // init 
{
    if (rhs.size) {  // if there is something to copy, clone the table:  
        internalPtr = new double[rhs.size];
        std::copy(rhs.internalPtr, rhs.internalPtr + rhs.size, internalPtr);
    }
}
```

You have of course to adapt your empty() to reintialise the size.

The assignement would then look like:

```
myObject& operator= (const myObject& rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs) {         //  ATTENTION:  Check that's not a copy on one self bbefore deallocaing !! 
        empty(); //this will delete[] internalPtr
        internalPtr = new double[rhs.size];
        size = rhs.size; 
        std::copy(rhs.internalPtr, rhs.internalPtr + rhs.size, internalPtr);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Your original code is a very good example of what could go wrong if object would be assigned to itself.  Look at the coment above, on how to avoid this.

The `add()` would then look like:

```
myObject add(myObject A, myObject B)
{
    myObject C = A;   // create C by cloning object A 
    //simple code to add B to C 
    return C;
}
```

By the way, if you make this function a friend of your class, the simple code would really look simple, like:

```
    int sz = min(C.size, B.size);  // avoid out of bounds if B is bigger or smaller than C
    std::transform (C.internalPtr, C.internalPtr + sz, B.internalPtr, C.internalPtr, std::plus<double>());
```

Comment: Swapped two lines of your `operator=` so that a `bad_alloc` would leave it in a valid state (depending on how `empty()` is implemented).